# Changing initialized variable in assembler

Tags: assembly, arm

I have a variable like this at the start of the code:

```
    @;-- .data. Initialized data ---
    .data
        .align 2
        seed32: .word 0xffffffff    @;seed value (initial seed cannot be 0)
```

Comment: `LDR R0,=seed32` / `MOV R1,#123` / `STR R1,[R0]` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes this works the problem is changing the value of seed32 which is declared first time in .data.
For example:
.data
  seed32: AAA;;;
mov r0,BBB;;;
Now I want to insert the value of r0 into seed32 so when the program loops the seed32 is changed so It makes like a "random" seed each time. Thanks

Comment: Changing the value of `seed32` was exactly what I showed how to do in my previous comment. So if that worked, I don't see what the problem is anymore.

Comment: Thanks! IT seems to work, sorry I did not notice tha last part. THANKS! I really appreciate your effort!.

One last think, how can I add or mov hexa code, I'm trying this mov r2, 0x0019660D  and does not work neither does this mov r2, #0x0019660D.

Comment: You can only load immediates that follow the formula `imm8 ROR imm4*2` with `MOV` (on ARMv6T2 and later you can also load 16-bit immediates). To load other immediates, use the psuedo-instruction `LDR Rn,=imm` (for example, `LDR R2,=0x0019660D`).

Comment: Thanks it WORKED for the MOV I had perfectly but not on the instruction add (add r4,=0x3C6EF35F). Sorry for bothering you so much it's just that I'm completly clueless.
Thanks!

Comment: The `=imm` form can only be used with `LDR`. To add/sub/mul/whatever an arbitrary value to a register, load it into another register first using `LDR`.

Comment: Thanks! Everything works or at least seems to work fine, now I will try to run it to see what happens.
Thank you!

Comment: Seems not to work, don't know why. It just  does not fill the matrix.

Comment: Damn not working. I don't really know where the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to find the problem but I'm not able to get where is it.
The matrix is not being filled.

Comment: Since you haven't posted your code it's impossible for anyone to know what the problem might be.

Comment: Ok, I post it now, I think it was not possible.
ED: I posted the code on the question since it was too long to post here.
Thanks

Comment: Some things seem to work like the loop but it does not fill the matrix and I don't really know if the seed is being updated. I'm using devkitPro and the built in debugger.

Comment: Do anyone have any clue of what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can only load immediates that follow the formula imm8 ROR imm4*2 with MOV (on ARMv6T2 and later you can also load 16-bit immediates). To load other immediates, use the psuedo-instruction LDR Rn,=imm (for example, LDR R2,=0x0019660D)"

Worked great.